# How can I filter time in a Dataframe column to output rows and count the different values on the other row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, logic

I have a dataframe with two columns, Time and State.
To create the time, I split a date and time column to create a new column as shown below.
The new time column is recorded in HH:MM:SS format.

`data['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.time`

There are two states, **Forward** and **Reply** and I wish to get a len() count for each of the states for values between 9:00:00 and 13:00:00. 
I tried the between_time method but it requires a date time index. Any ideas out there that could help?

*Sample data*.

For this sample, I used pd.DataFrame.head(). I edited the times for relevance to the question.

```
State      time
0       Reply  04:01:00
1       Reply  08:04:00
2       Forward  09:05:00
3       Forward  12:06:00
4       Reply  13:07:00
```

*Expected Output* :

> (9:00:00 and 13:00:00)
>
> Forward = 800
>
> Reply = 200

Comment: Could you add expected output?

Comment: Let me do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my answer based on some comments and the new sample data:

```
d = {'State':['Reply', 'Reply', 'Forward', 'Forward', 'Reply'], 'time': ['04:01:00', '08:04:00', '09:05:00', '12:06:00', '13:07:00']}
data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

>          State      time
>     0    Reply  04:01:00
>     1    Reply  08:04:00
>     2  Forward  09:05:00
>     3  Forward  12:06:00
>     4    Reply  13:07:00
```

`between_time` requires the indices of the dataframe to be of the correct datetime format:

```
data.index = pd.to_datetime(data['time'])

>                            State      time
>     time                                  
>     2019-10-19 04:01:00    Reply  04:01:00
>     2019-10-19 08:04:00    Reply  08:04:00
>     2019-10-19 09:05:00  Forward  09:05:00
>     2019-10-19 12:06:00  Forward  12:06:00
>     2019-10-19 13:07:00    Reply  13:07:00
```

Finally you can use the `between_time` function to get what you want:

```
data['State'].between_time('09:00:00', '13:00:00').value_counts()

> Forward    2
```

Comment: My biggest issue has been referencing the time column. I can't seem to find a workaround to include and find ranges of the time.

Comment: @Biyinzika have you look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html

Comment: I get a type error when I use between time. (TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex)

Comment: @Biyinzika a suggestion from @Quant Christo 's comment: `data['state'].between_time('9:00:00', '13:00:00').value_counts()`

Comment: Yes, I tried that but unfortunately got the same DatetimeIndex error.

Comment: @Biyinzika if you can post some sample data, we might be able to be of more help.